# Developer Sandbox existing data after refresh

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I've read articles on Sandbox refresh on [Salesforce Help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_refresh.htm&type=5) and it mentions about what happens to the data after refresh in case of Partial copy and Full copy sandbox, but nothing on a developer copy sandbox.

I know for developer copy sandboxes only metadata refresh is possible -- so the question is, what happens to the existing data in the developer copy sandbox after a refresh if ONLY metadata is being copied? Does it remain or get wiped off?

Assuming it gets wiped off since salesforce creates a new instance when we refresh - Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Yes once the developer sandbox is refreshed all the data gets wiped off and only metadata gets copied from the source

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Just curious, if it is documented somewhere; or are you saying this from your experience?

Comment: No I did not find any official document but based on sandbox refresh methodology it  behaves as such. I have explained the behaviour in my answer

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox refresh operation is implemented as a sandbox creation and deletion in a single step. It is exactly the same two steps you would do manually, except you'd have to first delete the sandbox, then create a new one, which could cause significant downtime. Once you understand this, you should be able to see why all the data is removed on refresh.

Comment: The data that are in a partial or full sandbox are copied from the source org, they don't come from the pre-refresh sandbox. You usually refresh because the metadata have changed in the source org, which can include objects & fields being created, modified or deleted. There's no way to keep the data in a dev sandbox because it probably won't match the refreshed metadata.

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh a sandbox it creates a brand new org with all the metadata and Data(Based on type of sandbox) and old org remains same till the activation of the sandbox which means once we activate the sandbox old org gets deleted and new org will remain. Please find the [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_create_refresh_delete.htm&type=5) which supports the same

So by this we can conclude that data will be Wiped off if we refresh the sandbox. I didn't find any document for the same.